# Where does the Secret Key go when initializing for PubNub object?

Tags: objective-c, swift, pubnub

Where does the Secret Key go when initializing for PubNub object? Currently I have:

```
let config = PNConfiguration(publishKey: "key", subscribeKey: "key2")
client = PubNub.clientWithConfiguration(config)
```

However, I do not see a parameter for `secretKey` given.

Comment: Hi there you have a good question.  Simple quick answer is that this isn't supported.  I've supplied more details in an answer posted below.

Answer (score 0):

## PubNub iOS **`Secret Key`** on Initialization

On iOS with the PubNub SDKs we do not provide you a way to supply the **Secret Key**.  This secret is not intended to be distributed on client code and should only be included on trusted code execution environments such as your data center servers.

In order to leverage the administrative power of the PubNub Secret Key, you need to pair your app with a cloud hosted service provider that can host your trusted code execution environment.  You will leverage a server-side SDK such as [Ruby, Go, Python, PHP, Java and more PubNub Developer Resources and SDKs](http://www.pubnub.com/developers/).  These server-side SDKs allow you to specify the PubNub Secret Key for securing your apps when using [PubNub Access Manager](http://www.pubnub.com/products/access-manager/).